# Using java,browser is working in Windows 7,not with windows XP for opening component from GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to open one component details from my GUI.It is opening fine with Windows 7.But throwing error when I opened it from windows XP  as with warning dialog "no default browser found".Can anyone help me?

Comment: provide more information about what you are using to develop this GUI (e.g. Netbeans, Eclipse, which plugin, etc)

Comment: Why not set a default browser in Windows XP as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems pretty self-explanatory to me. You have not defined any default browser in your platform and therefore the system is unable to perform the action you request. Setting a default browser can be done with the following steps on WindowsXP:

1. Open the control panel
2. Choose Add/Remove programs
3. On the left, press "Set program access and defaults"
4. Choose your programs and press "OK"

[image]